# InflateException in XML file caused by ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-fragments, classnotfoundexception, radio-group, inflate-exception

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #254: Error inflating class com.****.***.SegmentedRadioGroup
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.***.***.SegmentedRadioGroup
```

This is my `detail.xml` file:

```
<com.***.***.SegmentedRadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/segment_text"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/button_one">

    <RadioButton android:id="@id/button_one"
        android:minWidth="150dip"
        android:minHeight="40dip"
        android:text="One"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />

</com.***.***.SegmentedRadioGroup>
```

In `detailfragment.java`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Database db=new Database(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail, container, false);
    // ...
}
```

I got error at:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail, container, false);
```

Comment: Make sure `SegmentedRadioGroup` is a top-level or `public static` class If it is nested class

Comment: Yes,SegmentedRadioGroup is a public class

Comment: Is it nested? or top-level?

Comment: public class SegmentedRadioGroup extends RadioGroup {

 public SegmentedRadioGroup(Context context) {
  super(context);
 }